# React / NextJs, set select option state on change does not reflect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to do a simple router push in a select option with react, so far my router push works but I can't update my default value, I can't properly set my state, not sure what I am doing wrong here:

```js
const navigation = [
    { name: 'Profil', href: '/unternehmen/profil' },
    { name: 'Geschichte', href: '/unternehmen/geschichte' },
]

const SubNavigation = () => {
    const [selectedSubNav, setSelectedSubNav] = useState('')
    const router = useRouter()
    const onSubNavChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const subName = navigation.find((nav) => nav.href === e.target.value)?.name
        console.log('subName: ' + subName)
        setSelectedSubNav(subName)
        console.log('selectedSubNav: ' + selectedSubNav)
        router.push(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <div className="relative pb-5 sm:pb-0">
            <div className="mt-4">
                <div className="sm:hidden">
                    <select
                        id="current-tab"
                        name="current-tab"
                        defaultValue={selectedSubNav}
                        onChange={(e) => onSubNavChange(e)}
                    >
                        {navigation.map((navItem) => (
                            <option value={navItem.href} key={navItem.name}>
                                {navItem.name}
                            </option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
                </div>
```

The router push works, but I can't set the value in my select option to that value I am setting my state to.

Comment: use `value={selectedSubNav}` instead  `defaultValue`

Comment: @MaK that did not work same behaviour

Comment: ok with useEffect track router and find in navigation current path and then uptade setSelectedSubNav with found result

Comment: @MaK could you show me how you would implement that, I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

try update `selectedSubNav` with `useEffect`:

```
const navigation = [
    { name: 'Profil', href: '/unternehmen/profil' },
    { name: 'Geschichte', href: '/unternehmen/geschichte' },
]

const SubNavigation = () => {
    const [selectedSubNav, setSelectedSubNav] = useState('')
    const router = useRouter()

    useEffect(() => {
       const currentPath = navigation.find((nav) => nav.href === router.asPath)?.href
       setSelectedSubNav(currentPath)
    },[])

    const onSubNavChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const subName = navigation.find((nav) => nav.href === e.target.value)?.name
        console.log('subName: ' + subName)
        setSelectedSubNav(subName)
        console.log('selectedSubNav: ' + selectedSubNav)
        router.push(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
                    <select
                        id="current-tab"
                        name="current-tab"
                        defaultValue={selectedSubNav}
                        onChange={(e) => onSubNavChange(e)}
                    >
                        {navigation.map((navItem) => (
                            <option value={navItem.href} key={navItem.name}>
                                {navItem.name}
                            </option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
     )
```

Comment: Same bug, does not work

Comment: @jokmasuf It was my mistake cause you use href as options value and  i use ```name``` instead ```href```.  I edited code

Comment: Does still not work, but a strange behaviour accurs now, if I try to select a different option twice the selected value changes, only if I try it twice. If I do a basic select, it does not work only on the second try, strange..

Comment: @jokmasuf look at this [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-newton-zi16x?file=/components/SubNavigation.js), probably there is a problem with your code

Comment: @MaK You should probably use `router.asPath` rather than `router.pathname`, this won't work if routing to dynamic pages (which might be the case for OP).

Comment: @juliomalves edited, but in any case, there was no dynamic path in question